# skimage warning about data type

Tags: image, ipython, scikit-image

Why does this code snippet give me this warning and how to fix it?

```
%matplotlib inline
from skimage import io

io.imshow(io.imread('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png'))
```

Warning:

```
/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skimage/io/_plugins/matplotlib_plugin.py:51: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  out_of_range_float = (np.issubdtype(image.dtype, np.float) and
/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py:1400: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The 'box-forced' keyword argument is deprecated since 2.2.
  " since 2.2.", cbook.mplDeprecation)
```

I have skimage version 0.13.1. Thanks!

Comment: What is your IPython version? Could not reproduce in IPython 6.4.0.

Comment: @AndriyMakukha Weird. I have IPython 6.4.0 too. Actually, the warning went away after I upgraded skimage to 0.14.0.

Answer (score 0):

The warnings are due to deprecations in NumPy and Matplotlib versions that were released after scikit-image 0.13.1. As noted in the comments, upgrading to 0.14 fixes the problem.